# How do i create nested tabs in drupal 7 view?

Tags: views, media

I am trying to create an image gallery from view.

I have a content type called "Photo-Gallery" with fields  ***title of event,year,month and images***

I have created a view with this content type and created page with Unformatted list.I am trying to make a gallery based on the following layout. How can i code custom view template?I want this by Year wise and then Month .

Unfortunately i am stuck on half way. Could you please suggest me a proper way to code the  view to get the exact result.

[image]

Awaiting quick replies.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) Module along with Views Module to achieve this result.

A simple overview to achieve this might be:

> Since Quicktabs uses blocks as tabs, If you create a views blocks for each
>   single items of a content type and then add them to quick tabs
>   manually.

Look through this http://mtt.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/992921-how-to-add-quick-tabs-with-multiple-view-blocks-inside-a-specific-page to get an idea.

Comment: I have created the blocks for each year and added them to the quick tabs.But the issue is, i need to add the quick tabs when in create a block for each year.Now i can add till 2015 and show the tabs.But next year if i add a node with year 2016 and month January , how could i show it automatically?